# How to backup the database from php myadmin daily 2 times automatically

Tags: phpmyadmin

There are some methods to backup database from `phpMyAdmin` manually, but i don't need that , i need automatically taking backup daily the database from `phpMyAdmin`. 
if any body known this please help me.

Comment: Why not just use [mysqldump](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqldump.html) running as a cron job?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried this?
https://mysqlbackupftp.com/mysql-blog/backup-phpmyadmin-automatically/

[I have used the tool and it seems to work]